# How to configure Laravel Pint to use two spaces instead of the tabs

Tags: laravel, php-cs-fixer, pint, laravel-pint

How to configure **Laravel Pint** to use two spaces instead of the tabs?

I tried multiple stuff in my **pint.json** file here is the example containing some of them:

```json
{
  "preset": "laravel",
  "exclude": [
    "bootstrap/cache",
    "frontend",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "storage"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "array_indentation": true,
    "phpdoc_indent": true,
    "statement_indentation": true,
    "method_chaining_indentation": true,
    "whitespace_after_comma_in_array": {
      "ensure_single_space": true
    },
    "indentation_type": "space"
  },
  "indent_style": "space",
  "indent_size": 2,
  "indent_with_tabs": false,
  "indent": "  "
}
```

Comment: Hi, check `.editorconfig` file to verify that preset is set to `"laravel"` and the indent style is set to `"space"` with an indent size of `2`... then restart your editor/IDE.

Comment: @Vihorian since Pint is built on top of PHP-CS-Fixer, on phpcs you do like `PhpCsFixer\Config::create()->setIndent("  ");`

Comment: @francisco thank you for your comment...sorry I don't understand how to incorporate this in my project. Laravel Pint has its classes in the vendor folder and the only way to configure it, mentioned in the documentation is using pint.json.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub I have all of the above. Still when I run "pint" it uses tabs